# How to use the definition of linear independence to show pivot columns as independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given A=

$$                 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4\\
1 & 3 & 1 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can we use the definition of linear independence to show that the pivot columns of A are linearly independent? I understand that I can find the RREF(A) and look at the pivot columns, but how can I implement the definition of linear independence to show that pivot columns of A are linearly independent? In other words, how can I implement $$[a_1, a_3][x_1, x_3]^T=0$$ and actually show linear independence using our definition?

Answer (score 1):

First observe that all row operations on a matrix preserve the linear (in)dependence of the column vectors of the matrix. Thus, the column vectors of the original matrix $A$ will be linearly (in)dependent if, and only if, column vectors of $\text{RREF}(A)$ are.

We can calculate that $\text{RREF}(A)$ is

$$                 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, if one vector has a zero entry in row in which another vector has a non-zero entry, then they are linearly independent. An example of this is any pivot column and the previous column vector. So, for example, look at the piviot column in column three. Then the third and second column vector are linearly independent. This is because, no matter what number you multiply by, the zero entry will remain zero. And, since we can not multiply by zero, the two vectors will never be equal. Thus, if you find a pivot column, that column vector and the previous one must be linearly independent.

Now note that, if two vectors have exactly one non-zero entry in the same row, such as the first and second column vector, then they are linearly dependent. For a simple calculation, $3$ times the first vector is the second vector. So they are linearly dependent. Thus not all vectors in this matrix are linearly independent.

Though you did not ask directly about this, asking for the column vectors of $A$ to be linearly independent is just asking for a non-trivial solution to the equation $A x = 0$. You can find solutions to this by looking at the reduced row echelon form the augmented matrix.

Answer (score 0):

So you have determined that columns $1,3$ of $A$ are the pivot columns, by the RREF of $A$. For linear independence, that would be to solve

$$\begin{align*}
&&A\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\0\\x_3\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
&\overset{\text{Row operations to RREF}}\iff&
\begin{bmatrix}1&?&0&?\\0&0&1&?\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\0\\x_3\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}$$

The last line directly gives $x_1=0$ and $x_3 = 0$. So columns $1,3$ of $A$ are linearly independent.